# Distance between points (think geometrically)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

For this problem do I use the distance formula that I would use between two regular points?

$d=\sqrt{(x_2−x_1)^2+(y_2−y_1)^2}$

The distance between points $u$ and $v$ on the $x$-axis is given by $|u-v|$. Solve $|x-5|+|x-6|=1$ (think geometrically).

Comment: There are in fact many.

Comment: @SimonS:  I guess it depends on what one means by many.

Comment: Actually the possible range is $5\le x \le 6$

Comment: It would not be helpful to apply the "distance formula", since that gives the (Pythagorean) distance between points in the _plane_.  Since your equation only contains one variable, you want to think about "distances" along a number line.

Comment: By definition, in $\mathbb R^n$, A point, $X$, is on the segment $\overline{AB}$ if and only if $\|A - X\| + \|X - B\| = \|A - B\|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it as $|5-x|+|x-6|=|5-6|$

If $d(x,y)$ means the distance between points $x$ and $y$ on the number line, then this can be interpreted as $d(5,x) + d(x,6) = d(5,6)$. Which means that x is between $5$ and $6$. That is $5 \le x \le 6$.

[image: betweenness]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For $x\le5$,

$$|x-6|-|x-5|=1$$
So by adding the original equation,
$$2|x-6|=2$$
$$x=5/7\text{ (rej.)}$$

Similarly

For $x\ge6$, we get $x=6/4\text {(rej.)}$

For $5<x<6$, Let $x=5+k$, where $0<k<1$.

We have

$$|5+k-5|+|5+k-6|=1$$
$$k+(1-k)=1$$
which is true for all $k$.

So the solution is $5\le x\le6$.

Comment: The distance between points u and v on the x-axis is given by |u-v|. Solve 2⋅|x-4|=|x-10|, I have a follow up question. would you use the same process for this problem?

Comment: Sure. Given $2|x-4|=|x-10|$. For $x\le4$, we have $|x-10|-|x-4|=6$, so by substitution $|x-4|=6\implies x=-2/10\text{ (rej.)}$. For $x\ge10$, we have $|x-4|-|x-10|=6$, so $-|x-4|=6\implies |x-4|=-6$, which is impossible as $|x-4|\ge0$. For $4<x<10$, let $x=4+k$, $0<k<6$, we have $2k=|k-6|\implies k=2\implies x=6$